# Regular expression in oracle to match everything between parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

example:

```
select * 
from emp 
where empid in (13,2,333,4) 
order by sal;
```

required output: 13,2,333,4

I want an regular expression that matches anything between "(" and ")".

Comment: It's unclear to me if you want to parse the query string to return the parameters or if you are looking for a query that returns the parameters for the `in` operator

Comment: I would pass the above query to REGEXP_SUBSTR and it should return the output as 13,2,333,4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have newline characters, then this will work:

```
select regexp_substr(c, '\(.*\)')
```

This includes the parentheses as well as the contents.  I would get rid of them with a simple replace:

```
select replace(replace(regexp_substr(c, '\(.*\)'), '(', ''), ')', '')
```